# Using IF ... PREPARE ... EXECUTE ... DEALLOC to create a temporary block?

Tags: mysql, migration

What are the comparative benefits of these two statements,

```
SET @stmt = (SELECT IF(
  (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND
            TABLE_NAME = 'foo' AND
            COLUMN_NAME = 'bar'
  ) > 0,
  'DO 0',
  'ALTER TABLE `foo` ADD COLUMN `bar` varchar(32) NOT NULL;'
));
PREPARE sth FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE sth;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE sth;
```

vs..

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `proc`;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc()
BEGIN
    DECLARE _count INT;
    SET _count = (  SELECT COUNT(*)
                    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    WHERE   TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() AND
                            TABLE_NAME = 'foo' AND
                            COLUMN_NAME = 'bar');
    IF _count = 0 THEN
        ALTER TABLE `foo` ADD COLUMN `bar` varchar(32) NOT NULL;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
CALL proc();
DROP PROCEDURE `proc`;
```

I'm just wondering if either approach is prefered over the other?

Answer (score 0):

`NOT EXISTS` is more readable and does not need to go through to get a full count.

```
BEGIN
    IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
            FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
              AND TABLE_NAME = 'foo'
              AND COLUMN_NAME = 'bar' ))
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE `foo` ADD COLUMN `bar` varchar(32) NOT NULL;
    END IF;
END $$
```